# How to run .net WASM in React Native Mobile app through Xamarin-React-Native bridge?

Tags: android, react-native, xamarin, webassembly, aar

I want to run **react native project** in **xamarin android**. I have gone through the following. They are connecting React native and Xamarin using **React native bridge**.

https://github.com/voydz/xamarin-react-native

Following is my **package.json** code

```
{
  "name": "xamarin-react-native",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "bundle-android": "npx bundle-sample-android && npx bundle-sample-forms-android",
    "bundle-sample-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ../samples/SampleApp.Droid/Assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ../samples/SampleApp.Droid/Resources/",
    "bundle-sample-forms-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ../samples/SampleApp.Forms.Droid/Assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ../samples/SampleApp.Forms.Droid/Resources/",
    "bundle-ios": "yarn bundle-sample-ios && yarn bundle-sample-forms-ios",
    "bundle-sample-ios": "react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ../samples/SampleApp.iOS/Resources/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ../samples/SampleApp.iOS/Resources/",
    "bundle-sample-forms-ios": "react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ../samples/SampleApp.Forms.iOS/Resources/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ../samples/SampleApp.Forms.iOS/Resources/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.4"
  }
}
```

When I run the following commands

```
npm install
npm start
npm bundle-sample-android
```

My **index.android.bundle** file is getting updated in Sample project which is exactly what I wanted. But there is only one small problem. There is a file name **react-native-0.55.3.aar** which is already present in **Jars** folder. I need to replace it with **react-native-0.71.4.aar**. This **react-native-0.55.3.aar** file gives me error

```
Error occured while reading the file '..\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.55.3\react-native-0.55.3.aar'.
```

Currently I have downgraded my **Node** from **18.8.0** to **9.11.1** to use **react-native-0.55.3.aar**. It is working in the older versions of node. But my requirement is to use the latest **react-native-0.71.4.aar** and **Node 18.8.0**.  I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: that project has not been updated in 5 years

Comment: [OPINION] React native has advanced significantly since then. Pick one or the other of the two technologies, and stick with it. OR look into Flutter. Any of the three are quite capable.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve my requirement is to run .net WASM in react native mobile app. Creating API will take lots of time and webview is not a good approach so only way where I can do a workaround for making .net WASM and React native was through this Xamarin-React-Native way. Will flutter fulfil this requirement?

Comment: @Jason yes that's a problem also the developer of that project has not upgraded the project for a quite some time. But still I was able to successfully update index.android.bundle which will show my desired output. Only thing which is affecting is only one error that is react-native-0.55.3.aar which needs to replaced with react-native-0.71.4.aar. If that is done I'm confident that this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin build files are directly looking for that file. Update this:

```
<LibraryProjectZip Include="..\node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.55.3\react-native-0.55.3.aar">
```

in the `binding/ReactNative.Droid/ReactNative.Droid.csproj` file.

That said, this will very likely explode. The project is bundling very outdated AARs which are used by RN itself, so you will get a bunch of extra build conflicts by changing the core version, unless Xamarin is smart enough to discard those in favor of the newer ones required by the latest RN. You'll need to check the dependencies from the RN android repository, and update everything based on that.

Now, you want to do this in order to run WASM... react-native does not run WASM. In fact, react-native does not run all the JS code you want to throw at it. It runs the JS code supported by the embedded js engine, in the latest editions, Hermes, and Hermes does not support WASM:

https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/429

You would have to either link a different JS engine through JSI (which is kinda hard. I hope there's documentation now, but when I tried a couple years ago there was ZERO docs, in the entire internet, besides a chinese blog), or run through a webview. So you get a ton of extra work in each platform, and more slowness.

And on top of that, Apple does not like this kind of thing. Keep it mind.

Android-wise, your best bet is to use

```
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/jsengine
```

Or link to an embeddable JS engine able to execute WASM (maybe Zipline)